# Changing the loop approach to another one

Tags: c++, c

I change the code :

```
for(double i=0;i<=1;i+=a){//0<a<1
    for(double j=0;j+i<=1;j+=c){//0<c<1
        [...]
    }
}
```

To:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    do {
        iCycle[i]=i*a;
        for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
            do{
                jCycle[j]=j*c;
            }
            while(iCycle[i]+jCycle[j]<=1);  
            jCycleNum=j;
        }
    }
    while(iCycle[i]<=1);
    iCycleNum=i;
}

for(int i=0;i<iCycleNum;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<jCycleNum;j++){
        [...]
    }
}
```

I change the approach because I want to get the value of the iCycleNum and jCycleNum,iCycleNum is the loop number of the `for(double i=0;i<=1;i+=a)`, the jCycleNum is the loop number of the `for(double j=0;j+i<=1;j+=c)`. But I think something wrong is happened in my new code.
What am I missing?
Can somebody help me ?

Add:
I want to get the loop number of `for(double i=0;i<=1;i+=a)` and `for(double j=0;j+i<=1;j+=c)` , and the every loop the value of `i` and `j` then put them in array .

Comment: It isn't very clear what the issue is, please consider reading the following page http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you tell specifically that what is it doing wrong. What behavior do you expect and what behavior are you getting

Comment: You have two while loops in your code that do nothing. For what purpose have you included them in your code?

Comment: @TaimourTanveer Not exactly. These belong to the `do` statement. It's just a poor choice of indentation, since one normally places the `while` after the `do` closing brace.

Comment: I have already reedit my description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both codes are not equivalent, as iCycleNum will always be 99.

If you want number of iterations of each loop you can add this variable to your first code.

Since you cannot use vector we have a little problem. If you know maximum iterations at compile time you can do something like this (I assumed the max is equal for both i and j):

```
double iCycle[maxIters], jCycle[maxIters];

int iCycleNum = 0, jCycleNum = 0;
for(double i=0; i<=1; i+=a, ++iCycleNum){//0<a<1
    iCycle[iCycleNum] = i;
    for(double j=0; j+i<=1; j+=c, ++jCycleNum){//0<c<1
        jCycle[jCycleNum] = j;
        [...]
    }
}
```

In case you don't know maxIters at compile time and at runtime, you will need to change first line to:

```
dobule *iCycle, *jCycle;
iCycle = new double[maxIters];
jCycle = new double[maxIters];
```

But in this case you have to remember to do:

```
delete[] iCycle;
delete[] jCycle;
```

When you are done.

Is this solution to your problem?

Comment: I want the value of every i,j and put them into the array. @Lukasz Daniluk

Comment: Oh, now I understand, wait a moment.

Comment: Sorry,I can not use vector in my code,because I must run my code on CUDA, and it does not support the stl like vector,I can only put the i,j in new array like a[],b[]. @Lukasz Daniluk

Comment: No problem. Get in touch if you will need further assistance

Comment: If I do not know the maximum iterations, may I just fill a number just like 1000?

Comment: As long as you are sure it's greater than it. If not, you will be reading/writing outside arrays boundaries, which will result in undefined behavior (crash probably). You can go with dynamic allocation( new[] / delete[] ) and compute max iters as 1+(1/a) for iCycle and 1+(1/c) for jCycle. It should work I think.
EDIT: I think this +1 to the size is not necessary.